# Can not return maybe result in the IO Monad

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I do not understand why this sample of code does not work and in [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html) book it works:

```
module Monads where 
    import Data.Maybe
    import Control.Monad
    amap=[("a",1),("bb",2)]
    bmap=[(1,100),(2,200)]
    final=[(100,1000),(200,2000)]

    f::String->IO (Maybe Int)
    f par=do
          a<-lookup par amap
          b<-lookup a bmap
          lookup b final
```

It does not work and i do not understand how it could work since the last line returns a `Maybe something` and not a `IO something`.

I have also tried changing the last line to :
`return (lookup b final)` 
which to my reasoning should be perfect ( lookup returns a `Maybe Int` and then wrap it with `return`)

I get the following error in when using `return`

```
* Couldn't match type `Maybe' with `IO'
      Expected type: IO Integer
        Actual type: Maybe Integer
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: b <- lookup a bmap
      In the expression:
        do a <- lookup par amap
           b <- lookup a bmap
           return (lookup b final)
      In an equation for `f':
          f par
            = do a <- lookup par amap
                 b <- lookup a bmap
                 return (lookup b final)
   |
11 |           b<-lookup a bmap
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: The `do` block refers to `Maybe`, not to `IO` here. It looks like the entire thing should be `f par = return $ do ...`, or you could change the type to `f::String->Maybe Int`.

Comment: You're right, this will never work (it would if the return type was `Maybe Int` though). But I don't see that code snippet anywhere in the chapter you linked to. (I actually went through much of RWH not long ago - it's pretty out of date and a lot of the modules they use don't seem to exist any more with the same API - but I don't remember anything like this.)

Comment: It is right before `The list Monad` subchapter.

Comment: Nothing in your code suggests that `f` has to return an `IO` value.

Comment: Wait a second..i thought that when using `do` it is restricted only to the `IO` monad.

Comment: No, `do` works for *any* monad.

Comment: All you really need here, though,  is `f :: String -> Maybe Int` with `f par = lookup par amap >>= flip lookup bmap >>= flip lookup final`. IMO, that's clearer than using `do` notation, since it emphasizes the act of chaining several lookups together.

Comment: @chepner - the type signature of `String->IO (Maybe Int)` is what "suggests `f` has to return an `IO` value". If it had a type signature of `String->Maybe Int` it would be fine.

Comment: @RobinZigmond That's what I meant; the type signature is imposing an external constraint on the return type that isn't otherwise suggested by its argument or the lists it operates on.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian I just looked up that part of the chapter. Nowhere is the code you have put there listed. There are similar examples involving chaining `lookup` calls inside a `do` block, but nowhere is a type signature involving `IO` given for it. I think you are getting confused and putting things together that shouldn't be together.

Comment: Even simpler (though requiring an import from `Control.Monad`): `f = let lookup' = flip lookup in lookup' amap >=> lookup' bmap >=> lookup' final`.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion and the book example.I thought `do` can only be used in the `IO` monad hence i defined my method return type. as `IO( Maybe Int)`.Apologies

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian - no need to apologise, I'm always happy to help and I'm sure that applies to the others who've commented as well. For what it's worth, I wouldn't recommend RWH as the sole resource for learning Haskell. The best "book-style" resources for beginners that I've come across are [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) and the [Haskell wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell) (the more advanced chapters of that are very patchy but still full of good information, but the beginner-to-intermediate stuff is very good).

Comment: Yes i have looked through `Learned you a haskell` but what i come to realise is that after i finish a chapter with `RWH` even though its harder , there's nothing left to learn on that chapter in other books / tutorials( + i am halfway though) .For me it looks as a hardcore-complete resource (deprecated in some parts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the given type signature, you need to lift the value returned by the final call to `lookup` into an `IO` value.

```
f::String->IO (Maybe Int)
f par = return $ do
      a <- lookup par amap
      b <- lookup a bmap
      lookup b final
```

The `do` expression is syntactic sugar for uses of `>>=` that operate in the `Maybe` monad, not `IO`, in this case, but the `return` takes the resulting `Maybe Int` value and produces the required `IO (Maybe Int)` value. It could be desugared as

```
f par = return (lookup par amap >>= \a -> lookup a bmap >>= \b -> lookup b final)
```

However, aside from the type signature forcing you to use `return`, there is nothing else about `f` that *requires* it to return an `IO` value; neither its argument nor any of the three association lists involve `IO` in any way, so you could simply change the type signature to eliminate any reference to `IO` and operate purely in the `Maybe` monad.

```
f :: String -> Maybe Int
f par = do
    a <- lookup par amap
    b <- lookup a bmap
    lookup b final
```

---

### An aside: getting rid of `do`

Since you are chaining together various calls to `lookup`, it would be nice if you could feed each result to the next call in a point-free style. In order to do this, you need to reverse the order in which `lookup` accepts its arguments. This is trivial to do using `flip`: `flip lookup :: [(a,b)] -> a -> Maybe b`.

```
f :: String -> Maybe Int
f par = let lookup' = flip lookup
        in lookup' amap par >>= lookup' bmap >>= lookup' final
```

Taking this a step further, you can remove the reference to `par` altogether by using the `>=>` operator imported from `Control.Monad`. Compare its type to that of `>>=`:

```
:t (>>=)
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
:t (>=>)
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c
```

Instead of starting with `Maybe` value, you *compose* calls to `lookup'`, and give your starting string to the function.

```
f :: String -> Maybe Int
f = let lookup' = flip lookup
     in lookup' amap >=> lookup' bmap >=> lookup' final
```